# How to re-deploy project as api executable with a new version

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script. I've created an apps script project and deployed it as API executable. After adding two new functions to Code.gs, I save it as a new version, version 2. Then I re-deploy it as API executable using version 2, but when I run my client application, I get an error message from `errors.HttpError` as follows

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "ScriptError",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "ScriptError",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

How can I re-deploy apps script project as API executable correctly?

Comment: Was the executable working when you first deployed it? Did you go through all of the steps of activating the Apps Script Execution API in the developer's console?

Comment: Another question: does it have the correct scopes? (A side note: I remember having this same problem and wanting to tear my hair out. I went through a bunch of steps from the docs that fixed it but I was never clear about what the actual fix was.)

Comment: Yes, the executable working was working when I first deployed it. After adding two new functions to Code.gs, I did these three steps, 1) click File > Save all, 2) click File > Manage versions..., then save new version, version 2, 3) click Publish > Deploy as API executable..., then select version 2 and click update button, what else should I do to activate the Apps Script Execution API? thanks a lot!

Comment: There are some steps that you must do in the developers console to activate the API. Here is the guide I was referring to: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js

Comment: Thanks for the guide you provide. I think I've completed the steps in the developer console to activate the API, though I referred another guide, Python Quickstart, because I prepared my client application using Python. From these two guides, SCOPES is defined as this url, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', shall I replace it with another url or add some other urls?

Comment: Any fix for this? I'm also facing the same problem.